# process.waitFor(timeout, timeUnit) does not work as expected

Tags: java, java-8, processbuilder

I am running a process using ProcessBuilder. 
This is the relevant code :

```
 ByteArrayOutputStream resultStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
 ByteArrayOutputStream errorMessage = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
 ProcessBuilder pb = null;

 pb = new ProcessBuilder("/usr/local/bin/convert", "-limit", "time", "50", "-", "-resize", maxWidth + "x" + maxHeight+">", "-quality", "82","png:-");

 System.out.println(pb.command());
 long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
 System.out.println("start time: " + startTime);
 Process process = pb.start();
 OutputStream stdIn = process.getOutputStream();
 copy(input, stdIn);
 stdIn.flush();
 stdIn.close();
 copy(process.getInputStream(), resultStream);
 copy(process.getErrorStream(), errorMessage);

 boolean exitStatus = process.waitFor(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
 if (!exitStatus) {
           System.out.println("Image processing failed with status " + exitStatus + ": " + errorMessage.toString());
 }

        input.close();

        System.out.println("returning");
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println(endTime);
        System.out.println("difference :" + (endTime - startTime)*1.0/1000 + " seconds");
        return resultStream.toByteArray();
```

The difference is 90 seconds, but shouldn't i get an the error message regarding failure after 15 secs?

NOTES : 
I am providing the input to the process using stdin, and reading the output and error streams as byte arrays.

Comment: We need more context, I suggest putting together a [mcve] so people can replicate the problem and help you with it.

Comment: StartTime should be set at the line juste before the waitFor. With your current code, you risk to take into account the time taken by the copy process.

Comment: You haven't included the body of the "copy" method, but it looks like "copy(process.getInputStream(), resultStream);" line will run until completion (end of output form the process) no matter how long that takes. Then, once you get to process.waitFor, that should return immediately. But you're still waiting however long the copy() command takes (which will be however long it takes the called process to produce output).

Comment: @JeremyGrand in that case, i do not get the start time in console until the process returns, so i had to put it before pb.start()

Comment: That is exactly your issue. Your process returns before you start waiting for it. So there is no issue with the waitFor.

Comment: @user1676075 copy is just copying between streams by reading 1000 bytes at a time. I get your point, seems valid.

Comment: @JeremyGrand i get your point as well, there is no issue with the waitFor, but i could not have worded the question better when i asked it, because i didn't know of the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As user1676075 stated, you `copy` method runs until your process finishes its output, so that you never reached `process.waitFor` before the process' completion thus never attaining the case where the `waitFor` returns an incomplete process code.

Comment: Thanks, although the question that i asked could have been worded better, this answer helped me understand what is going on, and that everything is working as it is expected to be.

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry I never addressed your actual issue. You should just have put the outputStreams in autoflush mode to some kind of data storage (a ByteBuffer or a file depending on the expected size) and waited for the process ending without the blocking copy method.

Comment: I ended up reading the output/error in separate threads. the waitFor then works as expected.

Comment: Whats the solution for this? I mean builder.start() has to run prior to getting outputstream / errorstream / ... and before waitFor can be called. So, do one has to start a separate thread and control this yourself? waitFor is kind of useless if so, because it is not reliable.

Comment: @momomo OP's issue was they tried to forcibly copy the output of the process to the standard output, copy was a blocking operation. They could have simply piped the process' outputstream to std::out and moved along.